# How to update a jira comment in my project, using the atlassian.sdk

Tags: c#, jira

I am using the following code to retrieve my current jira comments, I wish to update them when they contain the text "ordernumber:".

```
foreach (Comment comments in jiraIssue.GetComments())
                {
                    //if ordernumber exists, update body
                    if (comments.Body.ToLower().Contains("ordernumber:"))
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(comments.body);
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                        comments.Body = "Ordernumber: " + ordernumber + ", date: " + now.ToString("u");

                        jiraIssue.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. How do I update an existing comment?

Further info:
Using:
C#.NET framework 4.0
Atlassian.SDK 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

`Issue` and `Comment` are different resources, so saving an issue won't make any changes to its comments.

To update the comment there is [particular](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue/%7BissueIdOrKey%7D/comment-updateComment) REST endpoint, but checking the source of [Comment.cs](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/823eb30b92db8c28b8b713d67e48a813ea8af116/Atlassian.Jira/Comment.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) file I haven't found a way to update it.
It could be that this particular functionality is not implemented, so the easiest and quickest way to find this out is to contact library author (just create a ticket with your problem in the project's [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/issues?status=new&status=open)).